# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise KB3022398 could not be opened

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I started getting crashes of Http64.exe so I tried to run VS2015 repair from CP. After a while, it stopped working. I tried to run repair again but got error: KB3022398 This update package could not be opened. Verify that update package exists etc.. Then I tried to restore to point before I run the repair but id got me nowhere, still the same error. I also tried to install updates for windows(7).

Here is snippet from log file:

```
[1834:1460][2017-09-01T21:41:50]i304: Verified existing payload: vs_devenvLP at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{*Removed*}v14.0.23107\packages\vs_devenvLP\vs_devenvLP.msi.
[1170:1184][2017-09-01T21:41:50]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[1834:1048][2017-09-01T21:41:50]e000: Error 0x800700a0: Process returned error: 0xa0
[1834:1048][2017-09-01T21:41:50]e000: Error 0x800700a0: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1170:16B8][2017-09-01T21:41:50]e000: Error 0x800700a0: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1170:16B8][2017-09-01T21:41:50]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: VSSetupUtility_Start_vs_enterprise MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1077248  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1077248
[1170:16B8][2017-09-01T21:41:50]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x800700A0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1170:16B8][2017-09-01T21:41:50]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[1170:16B8][2017-09-01T21:41:50]w350: Applied non-vital package: VSSetupUtility_Start_vs_enterprise, encountered error: 0x800700a0. Continuing...
[1834:1460][2017-09-01T21:41:50]i304: Verified existing payload: cab9265880E3FC97D3E96FCEEBCB9E6CBC9 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{*Removed*}v14.0.23107\packages\vs_devenvLP\cab1.cab.
[1170:1184][2017-09-01T21:41:50]e000: Error 0x80070642: BA aborted verify of payload: cab9265880E3FC97D3E96FCEEBCB9E6CBC9
[1170:1184][2017-09-01T21:41:50]e314: Failed to cache payload: cab9265880E3FC97D3E96FCEEBCB9E6CBC9 from working path: C:\Users\Pajamac\AppData\Local\Temp\{*Removed*}\cab9265880E3FC97D3E96FCEEBCB9E6CBC9, error: 0x80070642.
```